# Re-download purchased film on iPad without iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I'm having real difficulty finding an answer to this problem and since the device is out of warranty, Apple want to charge £25 for me to even report the problem.

We have ONE film that we've purchased on the iPad mini but it was accidentally deleted. Everyone tells me I can simply download it from the store again for free, however the "cloud" icon is greyed-out. We decided to bite-the-bullet and buy it again, but that won't work either, it says we already own it.

I've been told that I need to fix this by connecting to a PC, but this iPad has always been stand-alone and I don't have iTunes (or anything else) loaded on a PC.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The trash can isn't visible. Can you advise how I look in it please?

Comment: @Buscar What 'trash can' are you referring to? This is iOS. Furthermore, could you expand on how this could relate to iCloud?

Comment: @Buscar I'm loathe to install iTunes to solve this problem, I'm certainly not going to install some third-party software from a site where they can't even write English properly in the HOPE that it does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I've got to the bottom of this now and there is the potential that some of the information may be useful to others so thought I'd submit the entire thing as an answer.

The reason why the "cloud" icon is greyed-out (and the root of the entire problem) is that the movie in question is No Longer Available from iTunes. I find this bizarre in itself, the movie is 800Mb but for some reason they need to remove that from their servers to save space...?!?

When the movie was first deleted and we tried to re-download it, it definitely still showed as being available in the store. I guess the metadata was still there but the movie itself was deleted.

This movie cost £10 around a year ago, you can buy it on DVD for less then £5. The lesson here is to have your OWN backups of material from iTunes because they take no responsibility for allowing you to re-download it later. I thought we OWNED this movie and Apple would guarantee our ability to download it onto any device at any time, but apparently I misunderstood that I was paying more money for a product substantially inferior to a DVD.

I found this out by phoning Applecare using the number from Jules' link below.

When going through the "Select an option" stuff, if I selected "iPad", they still wanted £25 to talk to me. By selecting "iTunes", I spoke to them for free. I spoke to a very knowledgeable person who was able to explain the problem and offer - if not a solution, then, at least, a form of compensation.

The offered me 2 movie-rentals by way of compensation, pretty useless for us but better than having nothing for our lost £10.

Answer (score 0):

When you can not download the movie, there are two things i would do

- Log out of itunes & appstore from the settings app. For help see [this link](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201248)
- preform a [hard reset](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559)

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the suggestions. I tried logging-out of iTunes and back in again - no effect. I don't have a 2nd Apple ID and the device doesn't give me the option to create a new one. I do have the security pretty locked-down on this iPad - could it be that I have to unlock something to be able to create a new ID? (Sorry about dumb questions - this is the only Apple product we have and I can't say this experience is steering me towards Apple at all :-) )

Comment: How did you want to report the problem, via applecare?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you call it, someone guided me to "getsupport.apple.com" which eventually got me to a point where I was allowed to submit my question - but only if I pay £25.

Comment: The webaddress is right, but you can try to call applecare to see if they can solve the problem for you. The right phonenumber for your country could be found on this page: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232

Comment: Thank you for this! I spoke to Apple and it turns out that the movie is NO LONGER AVAILABLE hence it can't be selected for download! There's enough detail for me to submit my own answer which may be helpful to others, but thank you for the clue that led to solving the mystery!